# How to Read&Write .tiff images in java using GDAL library

Tags: gdal, java, image, digital-image-processing

I searched many sites to learn about this but I didn't find anything.

I need step by step process for reading .tiff monochromatic image in java using Gdal library.

Comment: The first step will be to install GDAL so I recommend you **edit** your question to describe where you did that and then precisely where you are stuck. I think asking for instructions from scratch when you have given no precise details of what you have already done makes this too broad.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you have gdal and the bindings installed, and some coding ability, so I'll just provide an outline:

```
import org.gdal.gdal.gdal;
import org.gdal.gdal.Band;
import org.gdal.gdal.Dataset;

...
Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(filename);
Band band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1);
...
// Do some band operation, like band.ReadRaster() to get the data, whatever you need for your scenario.
```

There are [more examples in the GDAL sources](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/), like a [Java equivalent of gdalinfo](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/gdalinfo.java) which will show you how to get the valuable metadata.

Also, make sure you read the [Javadoc](http://gdal.org/java/) for whatever class you are using, and compare usage in the examples.

Comment: I had to call org.gdal.gdal.gdal.AllRegister(); first otherwise gdal.Open returns null.